# JPA calls the save method and executes the insert and update methods at the same time

Tags: java, jpa

`JPA` calls the save method and executes the insert and update methods at the same time. When saving, a json type field is set. If this field is included, insert and update will be executed at the same time.

I suspect it's a serialization issue

Comment: Always provide example code with your question. also please correct "JAP" to "JPA"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When saving, the json field may change due to the serial number. Even if the value does not change, the order or other changes may occur after saving; and the characteristics of JPA, if the entity changes, even if the save method is not called, update will be executed. .
So the solution is to add @EqualsAndHashCode to the json field